# Zip Files by Date

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, zip

I have a folder full of log files on a Windows machine (Windows server 2008 R2, or I could copy them to Win10), and I want to zip them by date.  I'd love to do this with native means (eg: CMD/BAT, Powershell) not having to install anything.  Perhaps my search terms are too generic, but I'm having trouble finding the magic spell to do this.

It should be able to work with mixed file types, and I should be able to select which date I want it to use.

So, as a sample set (US date format):

```
log1.log Created 1/1/19 12:59p Last Modified 1/2/19 1:09a
log2.txt Created 1/2/19 8:00a Last Modified 1/2/19 8:00a
log3.log Created 1/2/19 12:59p Last Modified 1/3/19 1:09a
```

Could become:

```
190102.zip
      log1.log
      log2.txt
190103.zip
      log3.log
```

Or:

```
190101.zip
      log1.log
190102.zip
      log2.txt
      log3.log
```

Comment: I deleted my comment. I can only guess that you and one other did not like it and downvoted it. I get it, one can't please all. I got it that you were new to PS, which is why I used an educational answer vs just writing the code for you, because based on what you are after, you'd never find a single source for you entire use case, unless I did. You have to do it in phases. 1 - How to find files, 2-get file properties, 3-format the date property, 4-group files by that, 5-loop that group and Compress cmdlet or .Net compression, 6-validate results. Individual searches are needed, then combine.

Comment: The theme and goals of site like this is to help you with code you've written that is not working, or that you are confused about. Not write it for you. You will see that sort of response form many. So, sine you say... 'I'm absolutely unfamiliar with PowerShell.', it is really important that you get ramped up to limit confusion, mistakes/errors, misconceptions, and bad habits, that you will most certainly encounter as you go down this and other PowerShell use cases.

Comment: There are tons of free training all on YouTube, MSDN Channel9, MS Learn and other sites. Just hit them up and look for 'beginning PowerShell', 'Intermediate PowerShell', 'Advanced PowerShell', 'PowerShell and ' or just 'PowerShell zip'.

Answer (score 0):

Folks will not normally do this, as per my comments above, but I will this time, just so that you see what I mean in how to go about this and learn from it.

As you will determine from the below, this kind of stuff would never be in one place, unless someone has already wrote it up and posted it. All will have potentially different approaches as well. So, you'd have to find one you planned to accept and deal with long term.

***Branching from my previous comments.***

```
<#
What you are after for full understanding is a multi-staged effort, using:

Get-ChildItem
PowerShell Date Formatting
Compress-Archive or .Net (depending on what PowerShell versio you are using)

Example:

if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 5)... 
{
    Compress-Archive -Path $FileSource -DestinationPath $ZipDestination...
}
else 
{
    # If PowerShell version is below 5x
    Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
    [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($FileSource, $ZipDestination) ...
}
#>


# Define file source and zip destation paths

$FileSource = 'F:\Temp'
$ZipDestination = 'F:\Temp\Archive'

# Get the first file and check for all properties to see what can be used
(Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource -File)[0] | 
Select-Object -Property '*' | Format-List -Force

<#
PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::F:\Temp\CombinedSources07Jun2017.txt
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::F:\Temp
PSChildName       : CombinedSources07Jun2017.txt
PSDrive           : F
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : False
Mode              : -a----
VersionInfo       : File:             F:\Temp\CombinedSources07Jun2017.txt
                    InternalName:     
                    OriginalFilename: 
                    FileVersion:      
                    FileDescription:  
                    Product:          
                    ProductVersion:   
                    Debug:            False
                    Patched:          False
                    PreRelease:       False
                    PrivateBuild:     False
                    SpecialBuild:     False
                    Language:         

BaseName          : CombinedSources07Jun2017
Target            : {}
LinkType          : 
Name              : CombinedSources07Jun2017.txt
Length            : 774
DirectoryName     : F:\Temp
Directory         : F:\Temp
IsReadOnly        : False
Exists            : True
FullName          : F:\Temp\CombinedSources07Jun2017.txt
Extension         : .txt
CreationTime      : 12/7/2017 12:38:36 PM
CreationTimeUtc   : 12/7/2017 8:38:36 PM
LastAccessTime    : 3/23/2019 3:51:12 PM
LastAccessTimeUtc : 3/23/2019 10:51:12 PM
LastWriteTime     : 3/23/2019 3:51:12 PM
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 3/23/2019 10:51:12 PM
Attributes        : Archive


Note that there is no Last Modified property, it's called LastWriteTime

Figure out how to format that LastWriteTime into a string you can use for your 
filename using PowerShell date formatting
#>

(Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource -File)[0] | 
Select-Object -Property FullName, 
@{Name = 'ZipFileName';Expression = {$($PSitem.LastWriteTime).ToString('ddMMyy')}}

<#
FullName                             ZipFileName
--------                             -----------
F:\Temp\CombinedSources07Jun2017.txt 230319 
#>



# Then check for all file and group file by that string
Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource -File | 
Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'FileName';Expression = {$PSItem.FullName}}, 
@{Name = 'ZipFileName';Expression = {$($PSitem.LastWriteTime).ToString('ddMMyy')}} | 
Group-Object -Property ZipFileName

<#
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                           
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                           
    2 230319                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\CombinedSources07Jun2017.txt; ZipFileName=230319}, @{FileName=F:\Temp\CombinedSources07Ju...
    1 251017                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\duplicates.csv; ZipFileName=251017}}                                                        
    1 181117                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\fsoVolume.docx; ZipFileName=181117}}                                                        
    2 160519                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\g4.txt; ZipFileName=160519}, @{FileName=F:\Temp\log.txt; ZipFileName=160519}}               
    1 021117                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\groups.csv; ZipFileName=021117}}                                                            
    1 150617                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\HostData.xml; ZipFileName=150617}}                                                          
    4 170519                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\key.txt; ZipFileName=170519}, @{FileName=F:\Temp\secrets - Copy.txt; ZipFileName=170519},...
    1 130617                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\msinfo.txt; ZipFileName=130617}}                                                            
    1 260717                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\msinfo.txt - Shortcut.lnk; ZipFileName=260717}}                                             
    1 290917                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\MyCsvData.csv; ZipFileName=290917}}                                                         
    1 271117                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\output.csv; ZipFileName=271117}}                                                            
    1 201117                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\Serverreport.csv; ZipFileName=201117}}                                                      
    3 060617                    {@{FileName=F:\Temp\TestFile_1.txt; ZipFileName=060617}, @{FileName=F:\Temp\TestFile_2.txt; ZipFileName=06061...
#>

# Check source and destination objects
(Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource).Count
# 22

(Get-ChildItem -Path $ZipDestination).Count
<#
The below error will occur becasue the folder is empty, thus ignore or 
write error code to handle it.

The property 'Count' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At line:1 char:1
#>

<#
Process archive source to destination, 
loop and compress the results to $ZipDestination
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource -File | 
Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'FileName';Expression = {$PSItem.FullName}}, 
@{Name = 'ZipFileName';Expression = {$($PSitem.LastWriteTime).ToString('ddMMyy')}} | 
Group-Object -Property ZipFileName | 
ForEach {
    if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 5) 
    {
        # Using PowerShell Splatting for human readability
        $compressArchiveSplat = @{
            Confirm = $true
            Path = $($PSItem.Group.FileName)
            WhatIf = $true
            CompressionLevel = 'Optimal'
            DestinationPath = "$ZipDestination\$($PSItem.Name).Zip"
            # Force = $true
        }
        Compress-Archive @compressArchiveSplat
    }
    else 
    {
        <#
        Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
        [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($($PSItem.Group.FileName), "$ZipDestination\$($PSItem.Name).Zip")
        #>
    }
}



<#
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "
F:\Temp\CombinedSources07Jun2017.txt
F:\Temp\CombinedSources07Jun2017.txt - Shortcut.lnk".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "F:\Temp\duplicates.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "F:\Temp\fsoVolume.docx".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "
F:\Temp\g4.txt
F:\Temp\log.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "F:\Temp\groups.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "F:\Temp\HostData.xml".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "
F:\Temp\key.txt
F:\Temp\secrets - Copy.txt
F:\Temp\secrets.txt
F:\Temp\Test.htm".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "F:\Temp\msinfo.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "F:\Temp\msinfo.txt - Shortcut.lnk".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "F:\Temp\MyCsvData.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "F:\Temp\output.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "F:\Temp\Serverreport.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "
F:\Temp\TestFile_1.txt
F:\Temp\TestFile_2.txt
F:\Temp\TestFile_3.txt".


If you want the above to actually do anything, delete or comment out the 
-WhatIf and -Confirm, then uncommnet the -force
#>

# Check source and destination objects
(Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource).Count
# 22

(Get-ChildItem -Path $ZipDestination).Count
<#
The below error will occur becasue the folder is empty, thus ignore or 
write error code to handle it.

The property 'Count' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At line:1 char:1
#>

<#
Process archive source to destination, 
loop and compress the results to $ZipDestination
#>


Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource -File | 
Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'FileName';Expression = {$PSItem.FullName}}, 
@{Name = 'ZipFileName';Expression = {$($PSitem.LastWriteTime).ToString('ddMMyy')}} | 
Group-Object -Property ZipFileName | 
ForEach {
    if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 5) 
    {
        # Using PowerShell Splatting for human readability
        $compressArchiveSplat = @{
            Path = $($PSItem.Group.FileName)
            CompressionLevel = 'Optimal'
            DestinationPath = "$ZipDestination\$($PSItem.Name).Zip"
            Force = $true
        }
        Compress-Archive @compressArchiveSplat
    }
    else 
    {

        Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem" | 
        Out-Null

        [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory(
        $($PSItem.Group.FileName), 
        "$ZipDestination\$($PSItem.Name).Zip"
        )

    }
}

# Check source and destination objects
(Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource).Count
# 22

(Get-ChildItem -Path $ZipDestination).Count
# 13

# Check the archive object
Get-ChildItem -Path $ZipDestination

<#
    Directory: F:\Temp\Archive


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                           
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM         491206 021117.Zip                                                                                     
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM            650 060617.Zip                                                                                     
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM          93326 130617.Zip                                                                                     
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM         202549 150617.Zip                                                                                     
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM           5911 160519.Zip                                                                                     
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM           1164 170519.Zip                                                                                     
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM           9109 181117.Zip                                                                                     
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM            336 201117.Zip                                                                                     
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM           1057 230319.Zip                                                                                     
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM            334 251017.Zip                                                                                     
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM            685 260717.Zip                                                                                     
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM            756 271117.Zip                                                                                     
-a----        5/23/2019   1:22 PM            183 290917.Zip
#>


<#
Verify Check the file count in each archive.

There is no cmdlet for this, so you need .Net namespace
#>


[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem') | 
Out-Null

ForEach($archive in (Get-ChildItem -Path $ZipDestination))
{ 
    <#
    This will get only files. 
    If you wanted files and folder count, 
    if any were there becasue of using -recurse, then more code is needed.
    #>
    "Checking contents of $($archive.Name) contains : " + 
    "$(([IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($($archive.FullName)).Entries).Count) file(s)."
}

<#
Checking contents of 021117.Zip contains : 1 file(s).
Checking contents of 060617.Zip contains : 3 file(s).
Checking contents of 130617.Zip contains : 1 file(s).
Checking contents of 150617.Zip contains : 1 file(s).
Checking contents of 160519.Zip contains : 2 file(s).
Checking contents of 170519.Zip contains : 4 file(s).
Checking contents of 181117.Zip contains : 1 file(s).
Checking contents of 201117.Zip contains : 1 file(s).
Checking contents of 230319.Zip contains : 2 file(s).
Checking contents of 251017.Zip contains : 1 file(s).
Checking contents of 260717.Zip contains : 1 file(s).
Checking contents of 271117.Zip contains : 1 file(s).
Checking contents of 290917.Zip contains : 1 file(s).
#>
```